# How do I add blank space to the sides of my webpage on computer but not on mobile?

Tags: html

In a website I'm creating, I want there to be blank space on both sides of a body with a different background color. When you look at the website on mobile, I want that blank space gone.

simple example for what I want seen on the computer:

(blue background) / (body with information and navigation / (blue background)

Does anyone have a solution for what I'm talking about? I originally had the body's width set to 55% and I could see the alternate sides perfectly, but that of course keeps those sides on mobile, making it hard to read any of the body.

I'm newer to programming so if any of this didn't make any sense just let me know.

Comment: google media queries

Answer (score 0):

Like @Johannes's comment says, you can accomplish this with media queries in CSS. They detect the dimensions of the device and will run CSS if the device width and height are within certain bounds. See more here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp